# Недоступна mongodb из Docker контейнера

Tags: mongodb, docker, devops

Как получить доступ к mongodb, запущенной в контейнере? Доступ нужно получить другому контейнеру той же сети.

Один контейнер зависит от другого, ниже compose-файл

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo_dev
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27019:27017"

  mongo_seed:
    container_name: mongo_seed
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - mongo
```

`Dockerfile` контейнера `mongo_seed`, который пытается получить доступ к контейнеру "mongo"

```
FROM mongo:latest
COPY elements.json /elements.json
CMD mongoimport --port 27019 --db mendeleev --collection elements --drop --file /elements.json --jsonArray
```

Логи mongo_seed

```
2019-03-09T13:03:37.216+0000    [........................] mendeleev.elements   0B/687KB (0.0%)
2019-03-09T13:03:37.721+0000    [........................] mendeleev.elements   0B/687KB (0.0%)
2019-03-09T13:03:37.721+0000    Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
2019-03-09T13:03:37.721+0000    imported 0 documents
```

Изначально думал, что mongo недоступна по причине ее неготовности на момент запуска контейнера, но потом попробовал запустить контейнер вручную `docker run -it dev_mongo_seed /bin/bash` и получил аналогичную ошибку. Ошибка так же и при попытке соединиться с mongo `mongo --port 27019`

```
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27019
```

Но если я попробую соединиться с mongo c машины-хоста все ок.

Где я допускаю ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

Стоило подробнее прочитать раздел docker-compose, [посвященный сетевому взаимодействию](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode). По умолчанию для контейнеров указан `network_mode: bridge` и контейнеры ничего не знаю о портах, которые доступны в хост-системе.

Простейшее решение - добавить `network_mode: host` для `mongo_seed` контейнера и он будет использовать сеть хоста, где и будет доступен нужный порт.

Answer (score 1):

> попробовал запустить контейнер вручную docker run -it dev_mongo_seed /bin/bash и получил аналогичную ошибку. Ошибка так же и при попытке соединиться с mongo mongo --port 27019

Смотрим внимательно на свои настройки.

```
ports:
    - "27019:27017"
```

На хосте порт - 27019, а в контейнере - 27017.

> Изначально думал, что mongo недоступна по причине ее неготовности на момент запуска

Да, нужно [ждать](https://github.com/Eficode/wait-for) пока база [подымается](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/).